# Using Slack slash command to run local app

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I want to write a Slack command to open Skype For Business (SfB).

The command will be something along the lines of:

```
/sfb my.colleague@company.com
```

SfB recognises the `sip` protocol, so I can type `sip:my.colleague@company.com` in my browser and it will open a conversation with my colleague in SfB.

However, on inspection of the Slack Integration pages, it seems that commands have to call a public url starting with http://.

There is an official Skype command for Slack, so I assume that what I'm trying to do is possible, and I'm just missing a step.

Answer (score 0):

Slash commands work a bit differently.

Once a users issues your slash command, the request URL you specified will receive a special HTTP POST request from Slack (see [here](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling)). You need an app running on that request URL (e.g. a Python script) that understands the format of the the slash request coming from Slack. And that URL needs to be reachable from the public Internet.

You can however open URLs on your local browser through Slack, albeit not in one step. Here is how it could work:

1. Use enters slash command
2. App responds with a message containing [text link](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_urls) or [link button](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#link_buttons), with your `sip` link.
3. User clicks on the link